# very interesting behaviour using CUDA 4.2 and driver 295.41

Tags: linux, cuda, driver, gpgpu

I witnessed a very interesting behaviour when using CUDA 4.2 and driver 295.41 on Linux.
The code itself is nothing more than finding the maximum value of a random matrix and labelling the position to be 1.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int MAX = 8;

static __global__ void position(int* d, int len) {
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
    if (idx < len) 
        d[idx] = (d[idx] == MAX) ? 1 : 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    int colNum = 16*512, rowNum = 1024;
    int len = rowNum * colNum;

    int* h = (int*)malloc(len*sizeof(int));
    int* d = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d, len*sizeof(int));

    // get a random matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        h[i] = rand()%(MAX+1);
    }   

    // launch kernel
    int threads = 128;
    cudaMemcpy(d, h, len*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    position<<<(len-1)/threads+1, threads>>>(d, len);
    cudaMemcpy(h, d, len*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d);
    free(h);
    return 0;
}
```

When I set the rowNum = 1024, the code does not work at all as if the kernel has never been launched.
If rowNum = 1023, everything works fine.

And this rowNum value is somehow convoluted with the block size (in this example, 128), if I change the block size to be 512, the behaviour happens between rowNum = 4095 and 4096.

I'm not quite sure if this is a bug or did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *always* check for errors after calling CUDA functions. For example, in your code the `invalid configuration argument` error occurs during kernel launch.

This usually means that the grid or block dimensions are unvalid.

With `colNum = 16*512, rowNum = 1024` you are attempting to run 65536 blocks x 128 threads, exceeding the maximum grid dimension (which is 65535 blocks for GPUs with compute capability 1.x and 2.x, not sure about 3.x).

If you need to run more threads, you can either increase block size (you have alredy tried it and it gave some effect) or use 2D/3D grid (3D is available only for devices with compute capability 2.0 or higher).

Comment: Yes, you are right in this particular example, however, as I mentioned before, even I set rowNum = 4096, and block size 512, it does not work.

Comment: @user1624864 With such configuration (colNum = 16*512, rowNum = 4096, threads = 512) the launch configuration is `65536 x 512`, which too should not work

Comment: OK, I see your point. Thanks, the large grid dimension is the cause of the behaviour. However, I simply left out all the error checking code in the post, not in production. So the question becomes in general whether or not the "cuda safe call" method provided by SDK together with the driver error reporting is reliable?

Comment: There was no complaints about this error previously although I have the error checking template.

Comment: @user1624864 The kernel is launched asynchronously, so any error it produces is reported by next synchronous call (in your case, the error should have come up at second `cudaMemcpy`). If you do not want mix up errors from kernels and other functions, you can call `cudaDeviceSynchronize` after kernel invocation. It is computationally expensive, but very useful for debugging.

Comment: yes, I know this is asynchronous, but the strange thing is my algorithm ran without any complaint. The only difference is that it runs much faster than it should be. I do not know if it is normal?

Comment: @user1624864: ran much faster = launch failure and did not run at all. You clearly are not performing the error checking correctly. Call `cudaPeekAtLastError` directly after your kernel launch and check the return status. That will detect invalid launch configurations.